# Formula for coordinates (lat, lon), azimuth and distance.

Tags: python, coordinates, spherical-geometry, latitude-longitude

I would like to know how to find a set of coordinates on a small circle some distance from another point.
[image: circles]

For example, lets say A = (39.73, -104.98) #Denver

B = (39.83, -106.06) #point approximately 50 nautical miles away from A along the great circle track to C

C = (40.75, -111.88) #Salt Lake City, approximately 323 nautical miles away from A

How do I get the set of orange coordinates when I don't know the angle but I do know the cross track distance?

For concreteness, lets say the outer points near B have a cross track distance of +- 30 nautical miles and the inner points have a cross track of +- 15nm.

And the points near C have a cross track of +- 25 nm.

Also I have an initial bearing from A to C of -1.34 #radians

Comment: you had to mention what software you can use, Qgis, arcgis .. ?

Comment: I am using Qgis but would prefer a python implementation.  Or just the math formula.

Comment: the easiest way is to make a geoprocessing script using python.

Comment: but what should be the inputs, they are A , B and C ?

Comment: @geogeek - Just "make a geoprocessing script"? I know python has extraordinary powers, given the right libraries, but this is a complex _spherical_ cogo problem! Please elaborate with a more detailed answer, if you can.

Comment: @NeckBeard -- Are the "cross track distances" actually _arc_ distances (along the circles) as you say and draw? Or are they _offset_ distances, perpendicular to ABC?

Comment: How much accuracy do you need? Formulas for the sphere are relatively simple and will generally err by a small fraction of 1%.  Formulas for a spheroid can be extremely accurate but typically require expansions using a few terms in a power series or trigonometric series. Don't let that discourage you--the code is simple--but the risk of making an error in precomputing and transcribing the coefficients is large and so such solutions should only be undertaken when they can be extensively tested.

Comment: I concur with whuber. When i said "complex" i actually meant in the _ellipsoidal_ case. In the _spherical_ case, the solution is simpler -- see my answer.

Comment: Can someone help me about my question? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122738/calculate-geographic-position-based-on-azimuth-distance-and-height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the unknown points *are* on the specified circles, and if you assume a simple circular reference surface (a sphere, not an ellipsoid), then it is easy to get the `angle` at A from AC to the unknown points:

`angle` = `ctd` / `scd`,  where

`ctd` is your so-called cross-track distance (what I'd call *arc* distance), and

`scd` is your small-circle distance away from A

Then you "just" calculate the new coordinates of unknown point, U, say:

`coordsU` = `traverse` (`coordsA`, `azimAC` + `angle`, `scd`), where

`coordsA`  are coordinates at A,

`azimAC`  is azimuth AC, (conveniently, you already have this in radians),

`angle` and `scd` are as above,

`traverse` is the appropriate function for the so-called "direct" problem of spherical trigonometry -- for now, left as a separate exercise for you to research, or already available from some library.

Comment: I believe this is offset or perpendicular rather than arc.  I am not sure here is the formula. xtd = asin(sin(d1) * sin(theta1 - theta2)). Where d1 is the distance to an orange point ~50 nm and theta1 is orange point bearing theta2 initial bearing.

Comment: @NeckBeard -- If you've already got the the orange point bearing, then the xtc distance is irrelevant! Just jump straight to the traverse() problem. Is that your _real_ question? How to "traverse" (that's one of the technical terms) from a known point, given a bearing and distance, to an unknown point, on the sphere?

Comment: I don't have the bearing that is the formula I would use to calculate it if I did.

Answer (score 3):

There is no one formula to solve this problem on a spheroid (since it's a partial differential equation which can only be solved by iterative means), but the solution is a trivial implementation of the "direct" problem (given a point, a bearing, and a distance, locate a point).  The US National Geodetic Survey has a [web site](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PC_PROD/Inv_Fwd/) with [FORTRAN source](http://www.ngs.noaa.gov/PC_PROD/Inv_Fwd/source/forward.for) (I converted an earlier version of this code to 'C' and Java without difficulty).

You'd need to determine if the cross-track distance should be a chord or an arc when calculating the change in bearing (inverse sine of distance/radius vs. a fraction of the 2*pi*radius perimeter).

EXAMPLE:

Assuming arc distance, the bearing changes 17.18873 degrees for 15nm,
34.37746 degrees for 30nm, and 4.43466 degrees for 25nm, so the problem
becomes:

```
name    lat     lon     bearing distance
B+30    39.73   -104.98 -42.40  50
B+15    39.73   -104.98 -59.59  50
B       39.73   -104.98 -76.78  50
B-15    39.73   -104.98 -93.97  50
B-30    39.73   -104.98 -111.15 50
C+25    39.73   -104.98 -72.34  323
C       39.73   -104.98 -76.78  323
C-25    39.73   -104.98 -81.21  323
```

which solved to:

```
name    lat     lon 
B+30    40.344  -105.715
B+15    40.148  -105.917
B       39.916  -106.034
B-15    39.667  -106.057
B-30    39.425  -105.983
C+25    41.167  -111.778
C       40.758  -111.883
C-25    40.345  -111.945
```

which looks right in this plot:

[image]

Comment: I suggest "Direct", instead of "Inverse", as the problem. The "Inverse" problem in cogo is to determine bearing and distance between two known points.

Comment: Doh. Yes, Direct.  Changes the URL as well, though

Comment: @Vince So basically just a while loop to increment/decrement the bearing and check the cross track.

Comment: @NeckBeard -- That's _one_ way of doing it i suppose, but not the one i'd want to announce to the world.

Comment: The answer i gave is essentially an elaboration of 2nd half of Vince's answer.

Comment: The iteration occurs within the direct() call, where the spherical "guess" is adjusted by the spheroidal "actual" until it's "close enough".

Answer (score 1):

Geodesic calculations like these can be done in python using
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/geographiclib.
Assuming you have this installed, the following python computes the answers you want

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python/site-packages")
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic,Math
NM=1852
MASK=Geodesic.DISTANCE|Geodesic.AZIMUTH|Geodesic.REDUCEDLENGTH
lata=39.73; lona=-104.98
latb=39.83; lonb=-106.06
latc=40.75; lonc=-111.88

gab=Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(lata,lona,latb,lonb,MASK)
print 'Points around B'
for dist in [-30,-15,0,15,30]:
    g=Geodesic.WGS84.Direct(lata,lona,
                            gab['azi1']+dist*NM/gab['m12']/Math.degree,
                            gab['s12'])
    print g['lat2'],g['lon2']

gac=Geodesic.WGS84.Inverse(lata,lona,latc,lonc,MASK)
print 'Points around C'
for dist in [-25,0,25]:
    g=Geodesic.WGS84.Direct(lata,lona,
                            gac['azi1']+dist*NM/gac['m12']/Math.degree,
                            gac['s12'])
    print g['lat2'],g['lon2']
```

Running this I get

```
Points around B
39.3452857009 -105.943379739
39.5808782474 -106.048518139
39.83 -106.06
40.0707028272 -105.975822882
40.2815616574 -105.802535085
Points around C
40.3357882212 -111.941310951
40.75 -111.88
41.1592654552 -111.775837558
```

Note that the cross track distance should be converted to a change in azimuth using the reduced length, m12, instead of the distance, s12.  It doesn't make much difference in this case; but if A and C were separated by a
greater distance it would begin to matter.

Comment: What is the definition of reduced length? I tried looking for it [link](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/java/index.html) but the documentation isn't very good.  Just trying to understand the difference between s12 and m12.

Comment: Consider a geodesic from A to B of length s12; the azimuth at A is alpha1.  Now consider a second geodesic of length s12 starting at A with azimuth alpha1 + dalpha1.  The second end of this geodesic is separated from B by a distance m12 * dalpha1 where m12 is the reduced length.  On a plane, m12 = s12.  For a sphere of radius R, m12 = R * sin(s12/R).  For an ellipsoid, Helmert gives a formula.

Comment: See also the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid#Differential_behavior_of_geodesics

Comment: Finally(!), I've modified my online geodesic calculator to return the reduced length to allow you to see how s12 and m12 differ.  See http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/GeodSolve