# Calculate geographic position based on azimuth, distance and height

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude, geodesy, geodesic, position

How to calculate the geographic position of an object in sky (Point B)(like an aircraft) from Home Point (Point A) based on only four variables:

Lattitude and Longitude at Home Point, Azimuth at point B, Distance from home point to point B and height of point B?

[image: example]

Comment: This is a *spherical geometry* or a *geodesy* problem.  See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81124/formula-for-coordinates-lat-lon-azimuth-and-distance for example.

Comment: @martinf I've lat and lon at home point, distance from point B, height of point B and the azimuth of point B. Is it possible to calculate lat and lon of point B with those values? I've already read about geodesic problem. However it needs the lat and lon of point B to calculate the lat and lon of home point.

Comment: Your problem is *exactly* the "direct geodetic" problem (or traverse).