# Finding coordinates by Azimuth in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, coordinates, distance, azimuth

In QGIS I am working on a forest project. I have one central point (I know coordinates of it), then I have azimuth and distance of trees from this central point.

How can I find coordinates of trees?

Comment: X = sin(azimuth)*distance and Y=cos(azimuth)*distance. If you do the calculations in a spreadsheet, you must convert your azimuts to  radians. For instance X=(sin(radians(azimuth)))*distance  and Y=(cos(radians(azimuth)))*distance

Comment: Here you have a similar question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81124/formula-for-coordinates-lat-lon-azimuth-and-distance?rq=1

Comment: I suggest you to use "Azimuth and Distance Plugin"

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to project the central point with your azimuth and distance values, using QGIS expression function [`project()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#project), then get the coordinates with [`x()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#id33) and [`y()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#id35). Be aware of projections, however, as you have to use at least two different CRS for this task.

*Expression used to create lon/lat coordinate values, based on the coordinates of the central point and azimuth and distance values, here in CRS 32339 (Madagaskar):*
[image]

If you have lat/lon coordinates, they are in EPSG:4326 / WGS84. Distances are in meters (or inches or whatever), however, so they are measured in another CRS, most probably a local CRS apt for measurements like e.g. the UTM zone for the region. You can't use EPSG:4326 for distance measurements. So you must perform a coordinate transformation twice with [`transform()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#transform) to get the correct values.

1. Transform the central point's coordinates form EPSG:4326 to the CRS used for the measurements.
2. Create the projected point in your local CRS, based on distance and azimuth values from the central point.
3. Transform the projected point back to EPSG:4326 to get lat/lon values.

For your local CRS, in the expression below you can use the varibale `@layer_crs` (CRS of the current layer) if the layer on which you apply the expression is in the CRS used for the distance measurements. Otherwise, replace the variable with the EPSG code in single quotes like this: 'EPSG:32638' (example for [EPSG 32638, UTM zone 38 N](https://mangomap.com/robertyoung/maps/69585/what-utm-zone-am-i-in-?field=gid&value=91&layer=ad409ec0-cf2c-11e7-847d-06765ea3034e)).

Thus the expression to use looks like this, where in line 5, insert the coordinates of the central_point, `@layer_crs` is the variable for your local CRS (see above). Replace `x` with `y` on line 1 to get the y instead of the x coordinate:

```
x(
    transform(
        project (
            transform (
                make_point (44.2048,41.5354), -- your coordinate values here
                'epsg:4326',
                @layer_crs
            ),
            "dist",
            radians("azimuth")
        ),
        @layer_crs,
        'epsg:4326'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in R (using the `sf` package with `dplyr`).

Since you didn't offer a reproducible example, I will just share snippets of my code. Note the center coordinates were recorded in UTM and asssuming you have seperate columns for X and Y.

1. Convert the azimuth to radians:

   azimuth_radians = (90 - azimuth) * pi / 180
2. Compute the change in the x- and y-coordinates of a point from the reference point, given a specific azimuth and distance.

   delta_x = distance * cos(azimuth_rad)

   delta_y = distance * sin(azimuth_rad)
3. Compute the position of the tree

   new_x = x + delta_x

   new_y = y + delta_y